# How to keep carousel arrows in the center even after zoom in/out, or update browser windows size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

[Fiddle](https://codepen.io/sn4k3eye/project/editor/Akyrky)

[image]
I have a chart, and my goal is to place the carousel left, right always verical aline center (50% from the top), and position both arrows about 5% away, but close enough to the graph.

I have a hard time getting this to work.
I've tried

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
    <div class="panel panel-filled">
        <div class="panel-body carousel">

            <h1>Network Bandwidth</h1>


            <div id="chart1Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand"><div class=""></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink"><div class=""></div></div></div>


                        <small class="lastSelectedMenu">
                            <span> Current Interval:
                                <span class="lastSelected" style="color: rgb(255, 235, 59);">day (3/25/2020)</span>
                            </span>
                            <select name="last" class="float-right">
                                <option id="default" value="default">Select Interval</option>
                                <option value="day">Day</option>
                                <option value="week">Week</option>
                                <option value="month">Month</option>
                                <option value="year">Year</option>
                            </select>
                        </small>

                        <canvas width="558" height="279" id="chart1" style="display: block; width: 558px; height: 279px;" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#chart1Carousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#chart1Carousel" data-slide="next" style="display: block;">
                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
/*    .carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
    margin-left: -10px;
}*/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left, .carousel-control .fa-chevron-right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 50%;

}
.carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {
    margin-left: -70px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.carousel-control .fa-chevron-right{
    margin-right: -1200px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background: none;
}

.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}
```

---

https://codepen.io/sn4k3eye/project/editor/Akyrky

If you can spot my issue base on looking at my HTML & CSS, please say something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a couple things and your codepen was read-only so I moved it to a new pen:

1. Your @media styles aren't wrapped in `{}` so those weren't getting applied.
2. You were trying to move the `.fa-chevrons`, but they are `span` elements and margin wasn't going to work.

Here's the complete code you had - without the base CSS, as the stack snippet has a character limit. My codepen link has all of it.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.4.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
  
    .item img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .carousel {
      padding-left: 45px;
      padding-right: 45px;
    }
    .carousel-control .fa-chevron-left,
    .carousel-control .fa-chevron-right {
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      font-size: 30px;
      top: 50%;
      display: block;
      transform: translate(0, -50%;
      )
    }
    .carousel-control.right {
      right: 0;
      left: auto;
    }
    .carousel-control .fa-chevron-left {}
    .carousel-control .fa-chevron-right {}
    .carousel {
      position: relative;
    }
    .carousel-inner {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .carousel-control.left,
    .carousel-control.right {
      background: none;
    }
    .carousel-control {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 30px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      filter: alpha(opacity=50);
      opacity: .5;
    }
  
</style>

<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="panel panel-filled">
    <div class="panel-body carousel">
      <h1>Carousel Issue</h1>
      <div id="chart1Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="chartjs-size-monitor">
              <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand">
                <div class=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink">
                <div class=""></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ltw5Pac.png" width="558" height="279">


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#chart1Carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#chart1Carousel" data-slide="next" style="display: block;">
        <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll see I added a little padding around the chart to show how the arrows will set next to the chart.

The biggest thing is changing the chevrons to block elements and moving them up `50%` of their height (15px up).

https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/RwPqdxj

Hopefully this helps you in the right direction. Let me know if missed what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank-you very much for you help, and tips. How do we make sure it also stay in the mobile screen-size ?

Comment: Ah...just don't wrap the styles in the media query. You may have to adjust it though if your chart container changes. Edited to remove the media query.